# User icons appear broken and webmaster pro's has lost it's stylesheet

Tags: support

All the profile icons on Stack Overflow and Meta appear broken, and [webmaster pro's](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) has lost it's stylesheet so is rendering as text.

Confirmed the problem through three different IP's each with a different ISP, and if it is a CDN problem I'm based in the UK.

What gives?

Meta - note broken gravatar images at screen shot:

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGM3X.png]

Webmaster Pro's - lost stylesheet:

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sR8ji.png]

Comment: Looks fine for me. I sometimes get that kind of thing when I am experiencing DNS problems and it can't resolve particular domains.

Comment: The CDN may be playing up in your area. Where are you located?

Comment: @Oded London, UK. I confirmed the problem through 3 separate IP's before posting. WmP has been rendering as text for about 30 minutes now. SO/Meta CSS work's but still no profile icons.

Comment: could you post a screen shot of the way how you see the issue? [your profile at Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/12685/toomanyairmiles) looks OK to me; I also checked one of your answers - it displays the gravatar and user-card popup just fine

Comment: @gnat screenshot's added to the question.

Comment: I'm just south of London and everything's fine here

Comment: North London here, no problem at all. Are you sure it is not your local cache (or the ISP cache)?

Comment: @Clive pretty sure, I remoted into one of the boxes at work (Zone 1) and that's showing the same problem as is my mobile phone. Weird!

Comment: @Oded flushed browser caches (and DNS), tried different browsers, and different boxes on totally separate connections. Odd that other UK based users are not experiencing the same problem!

Comment: @toomanyairmiles - Strange indeed. If you can rule out specific browser, machine and ISP, you may look at your DNS settings (if you are setup for a specific provider).

Comment: @Oded it's a standard virgin media connection at home, and bt at work, I guess I'll reboot the work connection in the morning and see if doing the same at home fixes the issue. All very unusual!

Comment: Assuming windows `ipconfig /flushdns` and see what happens...

Comment: @Oded already tried, the problem persists.